# Is it possible to have Thunderbird-like local folders in claws-mail?

Tags: email, thunderbird, imap, mbox, claws-mail

I like using claws-mail with an IMAP email account, but I need a way to move mail from my size-limited inbox to a local folder and still be able to search through it. Is this possible using a local mbox file or something? How?

Comment: Came here with the same question. Considering this is 10 years old with no answer I'm guessing not or the question has aged to oblivion. I'll try asking again.